# Cannot scroll up in Windows console using winapi and kernel32

Tags: winapi, rust, windows-console, kernel32

I need to scroll through the Windows console. For that, I'm using code from [a Microsoft C example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/scrolling-a-screen-buffer-s-window) that I've rewritten in Rust. I make use of the winapi and kernel32 crates. I know the code is not written according to the Rust guidelines, it is just for demonstration purposes only:

```
extern crate kernel32;
extern crate winapi;

use std::mem;

fn main() {
    for i in 0..100 {
        println!("Just some data to scroll over {}", i);
    }

    scroll_up(10);
}

pub fn scroll_up(rows: i16) {
    let hStdout: winapi::HANDLE;
    let mut csbiInfo: winapi::CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO = unsafe { mem::zeroed() };
    let mut srctWindow: winapi::SMALL_RECT = unsafe { mem::zeroed() };

    unsafe {
        // Get the current screen buffer size and window position.
        hStdout = kernel32::GetStdHandle(winapi::STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        kernel32::GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdout, &mut csbiInfo);
    }

    // Set srctWindow to the current window size and location.
    srctWindow = csbiInfo.srWindow;

    // Check whether the window is too close to the screen buffer top
    if srctWindow.Top >= rows {
        srctWindow.Top -= rows; // move top up
        srctWindow.Bottom -= rows; // move bottom up

        unsafe {
            if (kernel32::SetConsoleWindowInfo(hStdout, winapi::TRUE, &srctWindow) == 1) {
                // println!("SUCSESS");
            } else {
                println!("failed");
            }
        }
    } else {
        println!("failed");
    }
}

pub fn scroll_down(rows: i16) {
    let hStdout: winapi::HANDLE;
    let mut csbiInfo: winapi::CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO = unsafe { mem::zeroed() };
    let mut srctWindow: winapi::SMALL_RECT = unsafe { mem::zeroed() };

    unsafe {
        // Get the current screen buffer size and window position.
        hStdout = kernel32::GetStdHandle(winapi::STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        kernel32::GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdout, &mut csbiInfo);
    }

    // Set srctWindow to the current window size and location.
    srctWindow = csbiInfo.srWindow;

    // Check whether the window is too close to the screen buffer top
    if srctWindow.Bottom < csbiInfo.dwSize.Y - rows {
        srctWindow.Top += rows; // move top down
        srctWindow.Bottom += rows; // move bottom down

        unsafe {
            if (kernel32::SetConsoleWindowInfo(hStdout, winapi::TRUE, &srctWindow) == 1) {
                // println!("SUCSESS");
            } else {
                println!("failed");
            }
        }
    } else {
        println!("failed");
    }
}
```

I can scroll down `n` lines:

[image: Image Scrolling down]

I can not scroll up `n` lines. What could possibly go wrong here?

*Cargo dependencies:*

```
 winapi = "0.2.8"
 kernel32-sys = "0.2.1"
```

Comment: Why did you tag C ?

Comment: @Stargateur Because I had an link to an c example. And maybe someone with an background of c that has worked with winapi and kernel32 may know what is wrong.

Comment: Since there is no direct interaction with C code or a C library, I would advise removing [tag:c] anyway.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks I get the point but is not solving the problem unfortunately. It isn't scrolling up.

Comment: @eryksun, Your question `Are you trying to scroll up when the top of the window is less than rows?`. no, as you can see in my example I print 99 lines after that I scroll up 10 lines, and I followed your instruction and it does not go into the else statement, so it should not be that problem of to many rows.

Comment: Yes, It does return a integer wits can be 1 and 0.  It is returning an 1 so no errors.